# How does changing substituents change the electronegativity of the carbon atom attached to it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronegativity

I was wondering how electronegativity and charge of carbon atom is affected by switching the substituents.

For example, what will be the difference in electronegativity of carbon atom in $\ce{-CF3}$, $\ce{-CCl3}$, $\ce{-CBr3}$, and $\ce{-CH3}$.

Comment: @SourabhYelluru Electronegativity isn't conserved, but only [transferable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferability_(chemistry)) property. In every situation it's slightly different, so usually approximate/average values are used.